# Using pyautogui to avoid windows session lock

Tags: python, pyautogui

I created a short script using pyautogui module with the purpose of avoid a window 10 session to lock due to user but inactivity. But it's not working.

The script is moving the cursor a little each 120 sec.
Any idea why it's not working? Sometime ago I found on web a small program that was doing exactly the same thing and worked.

Let me just clarify that the script works (moving the mouse) but the windows 10 os locks anyway.

```
import pyautogui
import time

import win32gui, win32con
import os

Minimize = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow() #minimize current window
win32gui.ShowWindow(Minimize, win32con.SW_MINIMIZE) #minimize current window

x = 1

print("Application running...")

while x == 1:
    pyautogui.moveRel(1)  # move mouse 1 pixels down
    time.sleep (120)

#end of script
```

Comment: did you find an answer for this? I was doing the same thing, move the mouse +2 on the x axis and then -2 but it kept locking.

Comment: Unfortunately no